# A couple of questions regarding Java ExecutorService newFixedThreadPool

Tags: java, executorservice

Please note that I usually ask a question after googling for more than 20 times about the issue. But I can't still understand it. So I need your help.

Basically, I don't understand the exact usage of `newFixedThreadPool`

1. Does `newFixedThreadPool(10)` mean having ten different threads? Or does it mean it can have 10 of the same threads? or the both? 
   I executed with `submit()` methods more than 20 times and it's working.
2. Does `submit()` print a value? Or are you putting threads in the `ExecutorService`?

Comment: The [Executors API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool-int-) answers the first part of your question

Comment: 1. Means "10 different threads"  The threads are blocked and ready to run but they aren't doing anything until you start submitting tasks to the executor.  If you submitted 20 tasks, then 10 were executed and the other 10 were queue up (saved) until the first ones finish and then they were run.

Comment: 2. `submit()` doesn't print anything (unless maybe if you have detailed logging turned on) but if the task/job prints something then you'll see output after the `submit()`.

Answer (score 2):

Briefly, tasks are small units of code that could be executed in parallel (code sections). The threads (in a thread pool) are what execute them. You can think of the threads like workers and the tasks like jobs. Jobs can be done in parallel, and workers can work in parallel. Workers work on jobs.

So, to answer your questions:

1. `newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads)` creates a thread pool of nThread threads that operate on the same input queue. nThreads is the maximum number of threads that can be running at any given time. Each thread can run a different task. With your example, you can be running up to 10 tasks at the same time. (The documentation can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool-int-) with credit to @hovercraft-full-of-eels)
2. `submit()` pushes the given task into an event queue that is shared by the threads in the thread pool. Once a thread is available, it will take a task from the front of the queue and execute it. It shouldn't print anything, unless the `Runnable` you pass it has a print statement in it. However, the print statement may not be printed right when you submit the task! It will print once a thread is executing that particular task. (The documentation can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit-java.lang.Runnable-))

Answer (score 0):

Just refer java docs or JAVA API's description rather than googling it.
For your questions I have below comments .

Question 1  ->

ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

First an ExecutorService is created using the Executors newFixedThreadPool() factory method. This creates a thread pool with 10 threads executing tasks.

Executors.newFixedThreadPool API creates, a thread pool that ***reuses*** a fixed number of threads and these threads work on a s***hared unbounded queue***. 
At any point, at most nThreads threads will be active processing tasks.
If additional tasks are submitted when all threads are active, they will wait in the queue until a thread is available.
If any thread terminates due to a failure during execution prior to shutdown, a new one will take its place if needed to execute subsequent tasks.  The threads in the pool will exist until it is explicitly SHUTDOWN. 
After submitting even 20 tasks ,it worked with this thread pool.

Internally it calls below line of codes .
**public static ExecutorService newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads) {
        return new ThreadPoolExecutor(nThreads, nThreads,
                                      0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                                      new LinkedBlockingQueue());
    }**

Question 2- >  Submits a Runnable task for execution in Queue and it can also return an Object of type Future Object representing task. we can use Future's get method  to  check whether submitted task has successfully completed or not because it will return null upon successful completion.